# Why didn't Cloak of Levitation save Doctor Strange the first time he got stabbed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

Just before Doctor Strange got stabbed, Cloak of Levitation saved Doctor Strange lots of times. So why didn't it save him from a surprise attack?

Does the Cloak of Levitation see through its master's eyes? Or does Cloak of Levitation have a consciousness, having human-like attention attributes (which might be focused on the ongoing conversation)? Anything from the comics?

Comment: _"It's a fickle thing"_. Seriously, its powers are inconsistent, but it appeared to me that it doesn't have a 360-degree viewing angle, like you mentioned. Also, the force needed to pull Strange out of the way of the spear might be too destructive for him.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the movie that it *does* have a consciousness of some form.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, there's a much more logical explanation. If you watch the fight between Dr. Strange and Kaecilius closely, you will notice that the cloak only interacts with physical entities. Even when Kaecilius tries to stab Strange with a magical shard, the cloak only blocks his wrist, not the magic itself. Because the shard that stabbed Strange was thrown like a javelin, there is no way for the cloak to deflect it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the senses of Dr Strange are extended to the cloak.  If Strange is aware that he is in danger it will protect him or otherwise assist. If Strange believes himself to not be in any imminent danger so too are the cloak's defenses down. I don't know if "it's a fickle thing" applies here -although why not.  Though I am not familiar with the comic series, I can imagine more examples and explanations are within its issues.

Comment: Can you provide any sources that suggest your ideas, be it comic books, some quotes or scenes from the film?